# Java - How to get list of elements best on certain condition

Tags: java, java-stream

```
Solution{
  String question
  String answer

  public Solution(String question,String answer){
  ...
  }
}

List<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<>();

Arrays.asList(
    new Solution("Index1","a"),
    new Solution("Index2","b"),
    new Solution("Index3","c"),
    new Solution("Index4","d"),
    new Solution("Index5","ae"),
    new Solution("Index1","afg"),
    new Solution("Index2","adfg"),
    new Solution("Index1","ag"),
    new Solution("Index2","a"),
    new Solution("Index3","a"),
    new Solution("Index4","a"),
    new Solution("Index5","a"),
    new Solution("Index1","arrr"),
    new Solution("Index2","a"),
    new Solution("Index3","a"));
```

I always want to get last two sets starting from Index1 which are

```
new Solution("Index1","ag"),
new Solution("Index2","a"),
new Solution("Index3","a"),
new Solution("Index4","a"),
new Solution("Index5","a"),
new Solution("Index1","arrr"),
new Solution("Index2","a"),
new Solution("Index3","a"))
```

but I am not sure what is the best way to do that. I can think of reversing the list and then have a counter on Index1 which starts with 0
then do while loop to add it in a list until counter reaches 2. Not sure if this is possible with streams.

Comment: What does `the last two sets` mean?

Comment: starting from index1 is one set.

Comment: Is your order guaranteed for this list?

Comment: Yes. Index1 will be the start for a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to get the positions at which `Index1` occurs in the list of solutions. These represent potential start position of the sublist. You can do this by using an `IntStream` over the indexes into the solutions list. Then, take the second-to-last start point as the starting of a sublist that goes to the end of the list.

```
    List<Integer> starts = IntStream.range(0, solutions.size())
                                    .filter(i -> solutions.get(i).getQuestion().equals("Index1"))
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(toList());
    if (starts.size() < 2) {
        // not sure what you want to do in this case
    } else {
        List<Solution> lastTwoSets = solutions.subList(starts.get(starts.size()-2), solutions.size());
        lastTwoSets.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

It occurs to me that using an `int[]` instead of `List<Integer>` makes things slightly more efficient as well as a bit more concise. The techique is otherwise essentially the same.

```
    int[] starts = IntStream.range(0, solutions.size())
                            .filter(i -> solutions.get(i).question.equals("Index1"))
                            .toArray();
    if (starts.length < 2) {
        // not sure what you want to do in this case
    } else {
        List<Solution> lastTwoSets = solutions.subList(starts[starts.length-2], solutions.size());
        lastTwoSets.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a bit simpler with a normal for-loop than with streams. You can loop through the list and keep track of the indexes of the last two occurrences of `Index1`. When you know the second to last index, you can use the `subList` method to get your final list.

To make it faster, you can iterate backwards from the end and find the first two occurrences. You can then stop when you hit `Index1` the second time.

This example iterates through from the beginning:

```
int firstIndex = -1;
int secondIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i++) {
    if (solutions.get(i).getQuestion().equals("Index1")) {
        firstIndex = secondIndex;
        secondIndex = i;
    }
}

if (firstIndex == -1) {
    // There weren't two occurrences of "Index1", so I return the whole list.
    return solutions;
}

return solutions.subList(firstIndex, solutions.size());
```

Note that the `subList` method returns a view over your original list. This means that it won't iterate over your list a second time when you call it.
It also means that if you mutate your original list, the changes will be reflected in the sublist.

Comment: why not start from the end and get first two occurrences?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Yeah, that would be faster. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit tricky because the filtering criteria is multi-part, but this can be accomplished by counting the number of times that a question index has been seen, at most adding only 2 solutions per question, and stopping once `Index1` has been seen twice.

The filtering object for this criteria would be:

```
public class SolutionFilter implements Predicate<Solution> {

    private final Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean test(Solution solution) {

        Integer index1Count = counter.get("Index1");

        if (index1Count != null && index1Count == 2) {
            return false;
        }

        Integer count = counter.get(solution.getQuestion());

        if (count == null) {
            counter.put(solution.getQuestion(), 1);
            return true;
        }
        else if (count == 1) {
            counter.put(solution.getQuestion(), 2);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

To ensure that the solutions are added in reverse order, a loop is performed, starting at the end and progressing towards the beginning of the `solutions` list. Likewise, to ensure that the output list is not in reverse order, a `Deque` is used and the matching `Solution`s are added to the head of the `Deque`:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    List<Solution> solutions = Arrays.asList(
        new Solution("Index1","a"),
        new Solution("Index2","b"),
        new Solution("Index3","c"),
        new Solution("Index4","d"),
        new Solution("Index5","ae"),
        new Solution("Index1","afg"),
        new Solution("Index2","adfg"),
        new Solution("Index1","ag"),
        new Solution("Index2","a"),
        new Solution("Index3","a"),
        new Solution("Index4","a"),
        new Solution("Index5","a"),
        new Solution("Index1","arrr"),
        new Solution("Index2","a"),
        new Solution("Index3","a")
    );

    SolutionFilter filter = new SolutionFilter();
    Deque<Solution> filteredSolutions = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = solutions.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {

        Solution solution = solutions.get(i);

        if (filter.test(solution)) {
            filteredSolutions.addFirst(solution);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(filteredSolutions);
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
[{Index1: ag}, {Index2: a}, {Index3: a}, {Index4: a}, {Index5: a}, {Index1: arrr}, {Index2: a}, {Index3: a}]
```

This can be accomplished using a `Stream`, but it may be more complicated.